# .NET Disruptor async patterns

Tags: c#, asynchronous, disruptor-pattern

I am using [Disruptor-net](https://github.com/disruptor-net/Disruptor-net) in a C# application. I'm having some trouble understanding how to do async operations in the disruptor pattern.

Assuming I have a few event handlers, and the last one in the chain hands a message off to my business logic processors, how do I handle async operations inside of my business logic processor? When my business logic needs to do some database insert, does it hand a message off to my output disruptor, which does the insert, then publishes a new message on my input disruptor with all the state to continue the transaction?

In addition, within my output disruptor, would I use Tasks? I'm 99.9% sure I'd want to use tasks so I don't have a ton of event handlers blocking on async operations. How does that fit in with the disruptor pattern then? Seems kind of weird to just do something like this in my EventHandler..

```
void OnEvent(MyEvent evt, long sequence, bool endOfBatch)
{
    db.InsertAsync(evt).ContinueWith(task => inputDisruptor.Publish(task));
}
```

Comment: It depends on your business logic, but you can use `async void`, which was designed specifically for event handlers.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yeah, I was thinking about that. The only thing I'm worried about then is that I am losing out on the benefits of the disruptor(i think). All of my logic after my awaits won't really run within the disruptor and I'll miss out on all the cache friendliness of it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto no it won't. ContinueWith will run that lambda when the task returns. That method will return immediately then(OnEvent). I think not blocking in my event handlers is the correct way, I'm just confused if I'm supposed to then insert back into the input disruptor when the task completes.

Answer (score 6):

The Disruptor has the following features:

- Dedicated threads, which can be pinned / shielded / prioritized for better performance.
- Explicit queues, which can be monitored and generate backpressure.
- In-order message processing.
- No heap allocations, which can help reduce GC pauses, or even remove them if your own code does not generate heap allocations.

Your code sample does not really follow the Disruptor philosophy:

- `Task.ContinueWith` runs asynchronously by default, so the continuation will use thread-pool threads.
- Because you are using the thread-pool, you have no guarantee on the continuation execution order. Even if you use `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`, you have no guarantee that `InsertAsync` will invoke the continuations in-order.
- You are creating an implicit queue with all the pending insert operations. This queue is hidden and does not generate backpressure.

I will put aside the fact that your code is generating heap allocations. You will not benefit from the "no GC pauses" effect but it is probably very acceptable for your use-case.

Also, please note that batching is crucial to support high-throughput for IO operations. You should really use the Disruptor batches in your event handler.

I will simplify the problem to 3 event handlers:

- PreInsertEventHandler: pre-insert logic (not shown here)
- InsertEventHandler: insert logic
- PostInsertEventHandler: post-insert logic

Of course, I am assuming that the post-insert logic must be run only after insert completion.

If your goal is to save the events in `InsertEventHandler` and to block until completion before processing the event in the next handler, you should probably just wait in `InsertEventHandler`.

`InsertEventHandler`:

```cs
void OnEvent(MyEvent evt, long sequence, bool endOfBatch)
{
    _pendingInserts.Add((evt, task: db.InsertAsync(evt)));
    if (endOfBatch)
    {
        var insertSucceeded = Task.WaitAll(_pendingInserts.Select(x => x.task).ToArray(), _insertTimeout);
        foreach (var (pendingEvent, _) in _pendingInserts)
        {
            pendingEvent.InsertSucceeded = insertSucceeded;
        }
        _pendingInserts.Clear();
    }
}
```

Of course, if your DB API exposes a bulk-insert method, it might be better to add the events in a list and to save them all at the end of the batch.

There are many other options, like waiting in `PostInsertEventHandler`, or queueing the insert results in another Disruptor, each coming with its own pros and cons. A SO answer might not be the best place to discuss and analyze all of them.